# Q: Absolute Value Proof with Multiplicative Inverse

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Prove: $\bracevert$$\frac{1}{x}$$\bracevert$ = $\frac{1}{\bracevert x\bracevert}$, if x $\ne$ 0.

This is a solution I provided:

$\bracevert$$\frac{1}{x}$$\bracevert$ = $\bracevert$$x^-1$$\bracevert$ = $\sqrt{(x^-1)^2}$ = $x^-\frac{2}{2}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}$ = $\frac{1}{\bracevert x\bracevert}$

However, the solution provided by the text:

$\bracevert \frac{1}{x} \bracevert$ . $\bracevert x \bracevert$ = $\bracevert (\frac{1}{x}) . x \bracevert$ = $\bracevert 1 \bracevert$ = 1, so $\bracevert \frac{1}{x} \bracevert$ = $\frac{1}{\bracevert x \bracevert}$.

This conclusion is unclear to me and I am hoping somebody can clarify.

Any comments on my solution will also be a big help.

This material is very trying to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not general enough. It is just true in the very specific case where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the Euclidean norm. In that case, your solution is correct.

However, for a general norm, you use the fact that $\Vert 1 \Vert = 1$ which can be easily seen like so: $\Vert 1 \Vert = \Vert 1 \Vert \cdot \Vert 1 \Vert$.

If $\Vert x \Vert \cdot \left\Vert \frac{1}{x} \right\Vert = 1$ holds, one can just divide by $\Vert x \Vert$ on both sides to get the desired solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In general, can one show that if an expression equals 1 is true then the equation is valid?